# Sequelize upsert when using sql server

Tags: sequelize.js

can somebody tell me if a sequelize upsert works in sql server? I'm using, specifically, sql server version 2012.

I'm confused because, in the sequelize docs, they state ***implementation details*** for:

MySQL, PostgresSQL and SQLite, but not include sql server in the list.

So, I'm curious if it is posible to do an upsert when using sql server (2012).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer, but have you tried to do it? Have you looked at Sequelize.js code? It may help you to find the answer...

Comment: @denisazevedo, thanks for your answer. I just tried and received this error message: ***The method "upsertQuery" is not defined! Please add it to your sql dialect.***. Do you have some idea about the meaning of this message?

Comment: Just a guess: Sequelize does not support _upsert_ with SQL Server. I suggest creating na issue [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues) to ask for this SQL Server support. Maybe someone else knows the answer.

Comment: @denisazevedo, Issue added. Many thanks for your help ...

Comment: It's [issue#5846](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5846), currently closed, with a message of "You are welcome to attempt implementing it."

Answer (score 2):

> UPSERT is now supported on MSSQL using MERGE statement

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html

Answer (score 2):

It's work on MSSQL, I've used `upsert` on my expressJs that using MSSQL as database.
You can see that [here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-upsert)